# Heapsort. How is it possible so simulate worstcase-scenario?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

I am rather clear on how to programme it, but I am not sure on the definition, e.g. how to write it down in mathematics terms.
A normal heapsort is done with N elements in O notation. So O(log(n))
I just started with heapsort, so I might be a little bit off here.
But how can I for example look for a random element, when there are N elements? 
And then pick that random element and delete it? 
I was thinking that in a worst case - situation it has to go through the whole tree (Because the element could either be at the first place or at the last place, e.g. highest or lowest).
But how can I write that down in mathematics terms?

Comment: You want to define worst case specifically for heap sort mathematically? I don't think the end result will be very mathematical. More like meta-meta-code/math/text. And Big-O notation is with the uppercase letter O, not 0.

Comment: Yes sorry my english is a bit shaky. However I came up with log(2(n)), because in worst case the random element we are looking for is at the bottom of the tree and every next branch has two additional elements) - I hope it is clear what I meant.

Comment: Oh you want the answer in Big-O ? Worst-case for heapsort is O(n log n)

Comment: Oh, well, and what if I look for the max/min element?

Comment: Max in max-heap: `O(1)`. Min in min-heap: `O(1)`. Opposite cases in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)'s worst case performance is O(n log n), and to quote [alestanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225541/alestanis):

> Max in max-heap: O(1). Min in min-heap: O(1). Opposite cases in O(n).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806132/645270)'s an SO-answer explaining how to do the opposite cases in O(1) if you create the heap yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To build maxheap array worstcase is O(n) and to max heapify complexcity in worst case is O(logn) so HeapSort worstCase is O(nlogn)